# how do i convert this query to django orm?

Tags: python, django, orm

i have a query, how do i convert this query to django orm?

```
SELECT tem.urutan,tem.rentang AS lama_kerja, count(*) as jumlah
FROM (
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN employee_join_date IS NULL THEN '1'
    WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(date(now()), employee_join_date)) < 1 THEN '2'
    WHEN 1 <= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(date(now()), employee_join_date)) AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(date(now()), employee_join_date)) <= 10 THEN '3'
    WHEN 11 <= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(date(now()), employee_join_date)) AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(date(now()), employee_join_date)) <= 20 THEN '4'
    WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(date(now()), employee_join_date)) >= 21 THEN '5'
    ELSE '0' END AS urutan,
CASE
    WHEN employee_join_date IS NULL THEN '<>'
    WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(date(now()), employee_join_date)) < 1 THEN '< 1 Tahun'
    WHEN 1 <= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(date(now()), employee_join_date)) AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(date(now()), employee_join_date)) <= 10 THEN '1 - 10 Tahun'
    WHEN 11 <= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(date(now()), employee_join_date)) AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(date(now()), employee_join_date)) <= 20 THEN '11 - 20 Tahun'
    WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age(date(now()), employee_join_date)) >= 21 THEN '> 21 Tahun'
    ELSE 'Terdefinisi' END AS rentang
FROM employees WHERE (employee_resign_date Is Null OR employee_resign_date > date(now())) AND employee_is_resign = '2'
) AS tem
GROUP BY tem.urutan,tem.rentang
ORDER BY tem.urutan
```

---

result to this or json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6TJw.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.